# TypeError 'Purchase' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

views.py

def vendor(request,pk):
    current_shop = get_current_shop(request)
    instance =get_object_or_404(Vendor.objects.filter(pk=pk,shop=current_shop,is_deleted=False))

```
vendor = instance.pk

purchases = Purchase.objects.filter(vendor=instance,is_deleted=False,shop=current_shop)
vendor_return = VendorReturn.objects.filter(vendor__pk=pk,shop=current_shop).values('id','return_date','total','date_added')
transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(shop=current_shop,is_deleted=False,vendor=instance).values('transaction_category__name','time','amount','date_added','vendor')
product_schemes = ProductScheme.objects.filter(vendor=instance,is_deleted=False,from_purchase=False).values('date_added','total_amount')
price_drops = VendorProductPriceDrop.objects.filter(vendor=instance).values('date_added','drop_amount')


result_list = sorted(chain(transaction, purchases, product_schemes, price_drops, vendor_return),key=itemgetter('date_added'),reverse=True)

context = {
    "instance" : instance,
    "purchases": purchases,
    "vendor_return": vendor_return,
    'product_schemes': product_schemes,
    "price_drops": price_drops,
    "transaction": transaction,
    'result_list': result_list,
    "title" : "Vendor : " + instance.name,
    "single_page" : True,
}
return render(request,'vendors/vendor.html',context)
```

Comment: Hi, what is your *question*?

Comment: i have an error "'Purchase' object has no attribute '__getitem__' "

Comment: Okay, and what is your *question*?

Comment: i have a function in Purchase model ,hence i want to pass that function into my views.py

Comment: Okay, and what is your *question*? You know, the thing that you put a question mark at the end of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`purchases` is a normal `QuerySet` that yields model instances when iterated over. All your other queries are values querysets, these yield dictionaries when iterated over.

`itemgetter` will only work on objects that support key lookups, like dictionaries, models do not support this. You need to change all your queries to be the same "type" and use `itemgetter` or `attrgetter` appropriately.

A quick fix is to turn `purchases` into a values queryset

```
purchases = Purchase.objects.filter(vendor=instance,is_deleted=False,shop=current_shop).values()
```